# Custom prev/next Pagination icon background color with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a background color to the MUI Pagination prev and next icons but the MUI exposes only the `Pagination` element that doesn't seem to take a style object and apply it to the icons but to the `Pagination` as a whole.

Here's what I tried first:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => createStyles({
  page: {
    padding: '0',
  },
  icon: {
    borderRadius: '16px',
    padding: '0 6px',
    backgroundColor: '#b74d3e',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    color: '#fff',
  },
}));

const classes = useStyles();
```

Applying it to `Pagination` like

```
<div className={`${classes.page} ${classes.icon}`}>
  <Pagination count={16} />
</div>
```

resulted in all the styles rules applied to the whole `Pagination` element.
The second go was attempt to use the `PaginationItem` element which seem to require a custom element (`component`) to display it on the screen. I'm not sure how to provide one and if it's needed to change the icon background color only.

```
<Pagination
  count={16}
  renderItem={() => (
    <PaginationItem
      component={}
      classes={{
        page: classes.page,
        icon: classes.icon,
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

An empty `component` returns an error and React's `Link` didn't pass for a valid one.

How do I change the prev and next arrow icon background color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to determine how to style these elements is to inspect them in the browser developer tools to see what CSS classes are applied to these elements which could be used for controlling style overrides. In this case, `MuiPaginationItem-icon` seems to be the class you want to target.

Here is a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Pagination from "@material-ui/lab/Pagination";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    "& .MuiPaginationItem-icon": {
      backgroundColor: "yellow"
    }
  }
}));

export default function BasicPagination() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Pagination count={10} />
      <Pagination count={10} color="primary" />
      <Pagination count={10} color="secondary" />
      <Pagination count={10} disabled />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Pagination icon background]

Another syntax option is to leverage `withStyles` to create a customized version of `Pagination`:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MuiPagination from "@material-ui/lab/Pagination";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
    }
  }
}));

const Pagination = withStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiPaginationItem-icon": {
      backgroundColor: "yellow"
    }
  }
})(MuiPagination);

export default function BasicPagination() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Pagination count={10} />
      <Pagination count={10} color="primary" />
      <Pagination count={10} color="secondary" />
      <Pagination count={10} disabled />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Pagination icon background (forked)]